# Change value (scale) of x-label

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have a plot which looks like this:

[image: Plot]

I'd like the numbers on the x-axis to go from 1 to 10, so I can write the label as "Time (microseconds)"

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

There have been requests to see the code. I intentionally left it out because my issue is simply a case of presentation - altering the values on the x-axis without changing any of the data the plot is showing. The code I'm using is a bit too extensive considering the relatively simple thing I require, but for reference it's here:

```
def Asymmetry(Ch1,Ch2):

#Turning Ch1 and Ch2 data into bins of equal size
timesCh1, bins1 = numpy.histogram(Ch1,bins=200)
timesCh2, bins2 = numpy.histogram(Ch2,bins=200)
#Converting the int values in the time arrays to flaot to allow for division in next line
timesCh1  = timesCh1.astype(numpy.float) 
timesCh2  = timesCh2.astype(numpy.float)
#Combining Ch1 and Ch2 data to find asymmetry
Asymmetry = (timesCh1-timesCh2)/(timesCh1+timesCh2)
A0times = numpy.linspace(0,10E-6,200)
P_Lerror = numpy.sqrt(timesCh1)
P_Rerror = numpy.sqrt(timesCh2)
A0error = 2.0*(numpy.sqrt((1.0/(numpy.power(timesCh1 + timesCh2,4.0)))*(numpy.power(timesCh1,2.0)*numpy.power(P_Lerror,2.0)+numpy.power(timesCh2,2.0)*numpy.power(P_Rerror,2.0))))


#Asymmetry function
def A0(t, B, beta): #t = time, B = magnetic field, beta = detector angle
    gamma = 851.616E6
    return (-1.0/3.0)*((numpy.sin(gamma*B*t - beta)-numpy.sin(gamma*B*t + beta))/(2.0*beta))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(A0, A0times, Asymmetry,p0=(0.007,0.754),sigma=A0error, absolute_sigma=True)
errors=numpy.sqrt(numpy.diag(pcov))
#Set x-axis 
new_time = numpy.linspace(0,10E-6,1000)
new_A0=A0(new_time,*popt)

pyplot.plot(A0times,Asymmetry, label = 'Raw data')
pyplot.errorbar(A0times,Asymmetry,yerr=A0error, fmt=None, label='Error bars')
pyplot.plot(new_time, new_A0,"r-", label = "Fitted data")
pyplot.legend(loc=4)
pyplot.title('py15csa - Asymmetry Data')
pyplot.xlabel('Time (microseconds)')
pyplot.ylabel('Asymmetry')    
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: I think it's a bit confusing: whether you mean you want the complete scale to go from 0 to 10 or each tick on the x-axis should increment 1,2,3, ... Looking at the data, I think the answer is the latter. You need to show your code so we know how to amend it for the desired result

Comment: Yeah it's the latter. The input data all needs to stay as is, I just want the ticks on the x-axis to be manually altered for better presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your time data in microseconds, i.e., multiply the time data by 1,000,000.  For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some data
x = np.arange(1000) / 1000 * 10e-6
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 1e6 * x)

plt.xkcd()
plt.plot(1e6 * x, y)
plt.xlabel('Time ($\mu$s)')
plt.ylabel('Velocity (furlongs/fortnight)')
plt.title('This is a Sample Plot')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Produces a plot showing microseconds rather than seconds.  Note that this does not alter your data, it only generates a copy times 1E6 for the plot.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of this as a last resort. It's a fairly large project so I wanted to keep the data in a 'pure' form without having to manipulate it back and forth just for one plot. I guess if this is the only way then I'll do it. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the actual underlying data are not manipulated here, only a copy sent to the plot routine.  If you are plotting millions of data points, well, then yeah - it is doing a lot of extra work.  But then, unless your monitor is millions of pixels wide, you are plotting way more data than you can see anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing matplotlib with pylab:

```
import pylab
pylab.xlim([0,10])
```

Alternatively:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xlim([0,10])
```

You have to share the code you're using.

If you want to set the x-axis ticks, you can do something like this:

```
plt.xticks([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
```

Comment: You're missing the p from `pylab.xlim`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't really share the code as it's fairly extensive and uses a load of arrays, curve_fit etc to get to the plot above. It's a little beside the point anyway as my primary aim is to alter the way the x-label is shown, so it's surely more about the scope of presentation options in pyplot rather than anything else? The xlim method you provided acts mathematically and crushes my data to the side because the points still only go up to 1E-6.

Comment: I suppose I could alter the code so the calculations building up to the plot are 1E6 larger. However I was just wondering if there's a simple tool for manually writing my scale on the axes, rather than going on the raw data it uses.

Comment: Then it sounds like you want to set the ticks instead. Something like `plt.xticks([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10])`

Comment: The xticks method is having the same effect as xlim :s

Comment: And set the label with `plt.ylabel('Time (microseconds)')`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the offered solutions actually answers the original question, so here's how I solved a similar issue:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(14,6))
[plotting here]
x_ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(x_ticks,x_ticks/1000)
```

What I do is:
Firstly, I call [Axes.get_xticks()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticks.html), which returns an array of tick locations.
Secondly, I use these tick locations to set new tick labels by calling [Axes.set_xticks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html), which takes two arguments: locations of the ticks and the labels to be used for ticks.

In the example I don't modify the data or x-axis per se, but only scale the x-axis labels.